# Use of Redis server along with MongoDB while using Klov extent reporter

Tags: mongodb, redis, extentreports, extent, selenium-extent-report

I'm using klov extent reporter for generating HTML reports for my automation results logging.

But i see the documentation section of [klov](http://extentreports.com/docs/klov/) where the klov report can be used without Redis server. i Like to know what advantage i would get using redis server ? as i'm not aware of this.

I have gone through some docs on internet to know about but really want to know how its required with klov reporter ?

Comment: It's optional, but highly recommended especially for version 0.2.0 which is available on klov.herokuapp.com.  See reason in the answers section.

Answer (score 3):

Redis is an in-memory key value datastore, which makes it much faster compared to databases which keep data on the disk.

Most applications use Redis to cache frequently accessed data / information obtained after heavy computation in the memory to improve their speed.